# Activity's member scope and Asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-asynctask, scope

I initialize a member variable in my Activity class

```
private String test = new String("A");
```

then I use it to write to Log in a long time consuming loop in `doInBackground()` method of an anonymous AsyncTask launched from the Activity

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

     for (int j = 10; j >= 0; j--) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("DOINBACKGROUND ", test);
     }

}.execute();
```

**QUESTION**:
When I leave Activity while `Asynctask` is still executing, and **after Activity's `onDestroy()` is executed**, I see in the Log that the member variable is still alive and not destroyed. Can someone explain to me how is it possible?

***BOUNTY QUESTION***: 
the member variable is still alive because, even after `onDestroy()`, it isnt yet garbaged due to gc criteria and gc priority. This is ok.

But my doubt is if

- the 'test' member variable (and the activity's context) will not garbaged until the referencing asynctask ended its stuff, thus asynctask can complete its `doInBackground()` always and surely without crashing (although with a temporary memory consumption)

or instead

- the 'test' member variable will be garbaged sooner or later regardless asynctask is running, maybe resulting in an asysnctask's crash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't confuse garbage collection and the activity lifecycle.

An object can be garbage collected once all references traceable to it from GC root objects are gone.

`onDestroy()` is part of the activity lifecycle. Essentially the framework is done with the activity and is giving up any references it might have been holding to the activity and related resources.

When you instantiate an anonymous inner class, it gets an implicit reference to the parent object. To put it in another way, an anon inner class is always a non-static inner class. This parent reference is a reference to your `Activity`. You're then passing the async task object to an executor with a call to `execute()` and the executor holds the async task reference as long as it is needed, also preventing the referenced activity from being garbage collected.

---

> Thus the asynctask in my snippet example will complete its doInBackground() always and surely without crashing due to NPE?

Yes. But do consider the following:

- Make your inner classes `static` unless they specifically need to access the parent object. Since anon inner classes are always non-`static`, make them non-anonymous.
- Mixing async operations in objects with separate lifecycle (such as activities or fragments) is fragile and it is better avoided. Problems include e.g. cancellation, results delivery to a gone object, and keeping GC-preventing references to expensive objects such as activities.

Comment: Thus  the asynctask in my snippet example will complete its doInBackground() always and surely without crashing due to NPE?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, onDestroy() happens just before destroying the activity and asks the activity manager to release all the resources tied to that activity. It means that all the activity's resources will be candidate for being removed by gc. However, it doesn't force the gc to remove the resources from the memory, they are just candidates. These candidate will be scored by the gc based on their size, age, recency, type and etc and whenever the system needs more space, it asks gc to remove candidates and it does it based on their scores. The candidate with a higher score is most likely to be deleted first.

This is noticeable when you see a crash out of nowhere, even after you quit from your application.

You might be able to see this crash if you create another activity and call System.gc() on it.

Cheers
A.

Comment: Very clear. My doubt now is if, in this case, the member variable is still alive only because of the gc priority, but it will be garbaged sooner or later regardless asynctask is running, or instead if it will be garbaged only when asynctask (that retains a reference to the member variable?) ended its job.

Comment: The asyncktask object instance belongs to the activity and the activity is destroyed. So the gc has already marked all the variables as garbage. They will be removed from the memory though. If you want to run a long term task use other structures such as services or intentservices, depend on your situation. 
If you want to stick to your current solution, to prevent the crash in the background, you can define the variable inside of the asynktask object, and check the callback against null in your onPostExecute(). By doing this, it doesn't crash, although still the result would be lost.

Comment: Yes, my doubt is that this anonymous asynctask retains a reference to 'test' outer class' variable and so to the activity's context. Thus they, because referenced, will not garbaged until asynctask ended its stuff. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are definitely right! Here is the point! Unless the inner class is static, the inner class tried to create a reference, which is not strong reference, it is either weak or soft reference. When the container activity is dead and the inner asynktask tries to reach it, it ends up with a memory leak and we have one of these two situations: 1-The value stored in the memory is still valid and not removed by gc, 2-The value is replaced by sth else and it crashes.
Conclusion: OOP principles doesn't not recommended anonymous inner classes.

Comment: thanks, i will open a bounty as soon as possible to deepening the topic

Answer (score 3):

The member variable `test` will not be reclaimed by the garbage collector until the instance of the Activity is garbage collected.

The Activity instance will not be reclaimed by the garbage collector until the AsyncTask is finished because the AsyncTask is holding a reference to the Activity instance.

The AsyncTask instance will not be garbage collected until it has completed its work.

AsyncTask will complete the `doInBackground()` method without crashing. For sure.

Comment: thanks, very clear explanation of the chain of references.

Answer (score 2):

An AsyncTask is not tied to the life cycle of the Activity that contains it. So, for example, if you start an AsyncTask inside an Activity and the user rotates the device, the Activity will be destroyed (and a new Activity instance will be created) but the AsyncTask will not die but instead goes on living until it completes.

Then, when the AsyncTask does complete, rather than updating the UI of the new Activity, it updates the former instance of the Activity (i.e., the one in which it was created but that is not displayed anymore!). This can lead to an Exception (of the type java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager if you use, for instance, findViewById to retrieve a view inside the Activity).

There’s also the potential for this to result in a memory leak since the AsyncTask maintains a reference to the Activty, which prevents the Activity from being garbage collected as long as the AsyncTask remains alive.

For these reasons, using AsyncTasks for long-running background tasks is generally a bad idea . Rather, for long-running background tasks, a different mechanism (such as a service) should be employed.

Comment: Mine is just an attempt in order to be able to verify on the field some theoretical questions about referencing. In this regard, for example, I'm trying to use findViewById from the Asysnctask to retrieve and update a view of the Activity while the Activity is no longer visible (thus after pressing BACK or changing orientation). Well the result is that the Asynctask ends its work, the view's update is lost but I do not receive any exception, nor using findViewById in doInBackground () throw a runOnUiThread () statement, nor using findViewById in OnPostExecute () method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the async task is not static and it holds the reference to enclosing activity, preventing the activity to be garbage collected.

If you want to know how anonymous class can cause activity leaks refer this -[link](http://blog.andresteingress.com/2011/10/12/anonymous-inner-classes-in-android/)

Also you can try rotating the devices multiple devices and check if there are multiple instances of the same activity by using the following command and checking the no of activities.

**adb shell dumpsys meminfo your.app.packagename**

```
Applications Memory Usage (kB):
Uptime: 40343748 Realtime: 164852669

** MEMINFO in pid 16561 [samsung.svl.com.graph] **
                   Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
                 Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
                ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
  Native Heap     5708     5664       16     2380    20480     8849    11630
  Dalvik Heap     1163      972      136    27080    37459    29598     7861
 Dalvik Other      604      604        0        4                           
        Stack      288      288        0        0                           
    Other dev        4        0        4        0                           
     .so mmap     3569      992       72     2120                           
    .apk mmap       39        0        0        0                           
    .ttf mmap        0        0        0        0                           
    .oat mmap      539        0        4        0                           
    .art mmap      747      524        4      704                           
   Other mmap        5        4        0        0                           
    GL mtrack    10951    10951        0        0                           
      Unknown     2260     2260        0       92                           
        TOTAL    25877    22259      236    32380    57939    38447    19491

 Objects
               Views:       17         ViewRootImpl:        1
         AppContexts:        3           **Activities:        1**
              Assets:        3        AssetManagers:        3
       Local Binders:        8        Proxy Binders:       23
       Parcel memory:        3         Parcel count:       12
    Death Recipients:        0      OpenSSL Sockets:        0

 SQL
         MEMORY_USED:        0
  PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:        0          MALLOC_SIZE:        0
```